# Vue + Webpack: exclude config.js from being packed works, but it does not load

Tags: vue.js, webpack, config

**What I want:**

In my Vue project, when doing a `vue run build`, everything is packed (webpack) into the `dist` directory.

I could deploy this entire package to the test server, but since the test server needs another set of credentials (for database etc.), one file, namely `config.js`, must be different on each environment.

My strategy:

- exclude `config.js` from being packed into the app.12314...js bundle
- define `config.js` as being emitted unaltered as a file (via webpack's `file-loader`)

**What I did:**

In the Vue component files which need config data, config is included via:

```
<script>
  import config from '@/config/config.js';
</script>
```

I created a `vue.config.js` file for modifying the default webpack settings like this:

```
const path = require("path");

// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /config.*config\.js$/,
          use: [
            {
              // exclude config file from being packed. The config file should simply reside as a plain file on the
              // file system, since it must be replaced with the target environoment specific config file on the server,
              // e.g. for setting the correct database connection
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'config/config.js'
              },
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**What I expected:**

- `config.js` will be emitted as a plain file, not bundled => `dist` folder will contain a bundled `app....js` file and a separate `config.js` file
- I can deploy the content of the `dist` folder to the test server and the generated code will take care of *loading* `config.js` adequately, so that the components can use the config data

**Problem:**

Granted, `config.js` is now emitted as a file, so my `dist` folder looks like this:

```
.
├── config
│   └── config.js
├── css
│   ├── app.eb377513.css
│   └── chunk-vendors.2da46af1.css
├── favicon.png
├── index.html
└── js
    ├── app.724607ed.js
    ├── app.724607ed.js.map
    ├── chunk-vendors.426dad42.js
    └── chunk-vendors.426dad42.js.map
```

As you can see, a separate file `config.js`! All other JS code has been bundled into `app.724607ed.js`. So far, so good.

However, the application on the test server would **not** load `config.js`, so every component which tries to use the variables in it, fails.

I noticed that in Chrome's developer tools, there is no network traffic for `config.js`. Apparently, the webpack code does not try to actually load the file from the file system. I expected this to be the case automatically.

1. what am I doing wrong, what am I missing?
2. is this the best practice to exclude config file from being packed?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Webpack's `file-loader` does emit the file separately (good), but does not add code for loading it in the webapp (bad). I assumed that `file-loader` would take care of inserting the correct `<script>` tag in the `index.html` file, so that:

- the separately emitted `config.js` file will be loaded
- on the dev side, the syntax for using the `config.js` is the same as for the other (packed) artifacts, like this:

(in the Vue component file:)

```
<script>
    import backend from '@/utils/backend.js'; // <-- normal way of requiring modules in Vue component
    import config from '@/config/config.js'; // <-- would work the same, but actually will load emitted file
</script>
```

Unfortunately, seems I was wrong. Since Webpack does not care about loading the file in the webapp, I switch to a manual way, like this:

**Step 1: Emit as a separate file**

This one is important, since I want the `config.js` file to be separate (not packed and minified along with the rest of the Vue app). I already described how to do this in the question (define a separate rule for `config.js` and use `file-loader` for it).

**Step 2: Take care yourself of loading the config file in the webapp**

Since the `file-loader` does not add loading code, make it manually. In `index.html`, insert the following line:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/config.js" ></script> <-------- insert this line!
    <title>replayer-gui4</title>
</head>
```

**Step 3: change `config.js` to be compatible with legacy importing method (without ES2015 module)**

Now, the commonJS syntax is not viable anymore because `config.js` should be loaded by the browser. And I am not sure how to mix ES2015 type module loading (with native `import` syntax) with Webpack code (which would replace all `import`'s with Webpack loading code). So I decided to switch to a legacy method: let `config.js` simply register a global (yuck!) variable like in old times:

```
var config = (() => {
    return {
        databaseCredentials: ...
    };
})();
```

Consequently, in each Vue module consuming config settings, adapt the "import" code - simply remove the imports because the variable `config` will be avalailable globally anyway (after our changes in `config.js` in this step):

```
<script>
    // import config from '@/config/config.js'; // <-- commented out - or just REMOVE this line
</script>
```

**Step 4: Trigger Webpack to consider `config.js` at all**

The only caveat now is that since `config.js` is never referenced in a Javascript file in an `import` statement, Webpack would not "find" the file and would never take it into consideration. Which means that `config.js` also never would get emitted.

So, force Webpack to handle it, in `App.vue`:

```
<script>
    import configDummy from '@/config/config.js';
</script>
```

Note that we never use the `configDummy` reference (variable), this is just that Webpack finds it - and applies its rules to the file. The rule in this case would be: emit it as a separate file in the `dist` folder (i.e. produce a `dist/config/config.js` file)

That's it! We used Webpack's `file-loader` so that `config.js` is not minified and bundled into the application bundle, but kept as a separate file. Further we took care of loading it via `index.html` which means the config settings are globally available.

What I do not like about this solution is that the nice methodology with `import` methods is corrupted for this special file. But I found no simple solution which just would make Webpack take care of these things.

If somebody has a suggestion, I would be glad to hear!

**Update 09.04.2019:** No, this is NOT an ideal solution. This works for the packaging/deploying (the `npm run build` part), but **not** for the development server (the `npm run serve` part). In order for the dev server to work, I had to copy `config.js` into the path `public/config/config.js`, so that the dev server can find it at the place which `index.html` is telling it, i.e. `config/config.js` (this is resolved relative to the `index.html` file).

So, again: it works, but sort of clumsy. And I do not like this solution.

Comment: What I did was simpler: just add an entry to the `entry` param in configuration. For example: `{ entry: { app: './src/main.js', config: './src/config/config.js' } }`. However, I haven't found yet how to exclude that file from being minified by `optimization.minifier`...